# Adding an invisible Document Library to a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I'm added a document library to new SharePoint sites though the onet.xml file,

```
<File Url="FooDocsPage.aspx" Name="FooDocuments.aspx"  Type="Ghostable">
    <View List="Foo Documents" BaseViewID="10" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="3" ReadOnly="TRUE"/>
...
```

I need to remove this web part from the page so users don't see if, but I still need the library to exist, because I'm adding and retrieving documents to the library though code.

Is there an easy way to make the made the library invisible? Or move it somewhere not accessible to the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the list invisible by setting the list's [Hidden property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.hidden.aspx) via code to `true`.